# How to play WAV from url AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-builder

How to play Wav in AS3 Project ? ( Flash builder ).

need to play something like this:
http://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/Speak?appId=54DDE60EEC8761E8C1226AFE4A3FDBDB992E371B&text=hello&language=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't play external WAV files in Flash. See Kodiak's answer for playing MP3 files.

Answer (score 0):

Code copied from [`Sound` class reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html#load%28%29)

```
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://av.adobe.com/podcast/csbu_dev_podcast_epi_2.mp3");
var snd:Sound = new Sound();

try {
snd.load(req);            
snd.play();
}
catch (err:Error) {
trace(err.message);
}
```

Comment: but i need to play WAV from url not mp3 :)

Comment: Aw sorry... since it's a Microsoft webservice, I think they do it on purpose to force you to use Silverlight. You can either use another [Text-to-speech service](http://www.acapela-group.com/develop-with-text-to-speech.html) or try an Alchemy wav to mp3 converter which may be a bit overkill.